# Neo4j remove/set label and property in the same query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to remove or set a label and property in the same query, what are the rules?

```
MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
REMOVE n:German:Student n.address
RETURN n
```

or does it even cascade further

```
 MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
 REMOVE n:German:Student.address
 RETURN n
```

as well as

```
 MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
 REMOVE n.address:Student:German
 RETURN n
```

and

```
 MATCH (n { name: 'Peter' })
 REMOVE n.address.name.size
 RETURN n
```

The Set queries would look pretty much the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have more than one `REMOVE` clause, so yes you can do both in one query, like this:

```
CREATE (f:Foo { bar: 1 });

MATCH (f:Foo) 
REMOVE f:Foo   /* Remove label */
REMOVE f.bar   /* Remove property */
RETURN f;      /* Return empty node */
```

Comment: Thanks, that will help alot!